# Programming of a natural language interface

Tags: customization, interpreter, natural-language

I've just started using the Mathematica natural language interface and found it very interesting.  After doing some research, I found some documentation on the "Programmable Linguistic Interface":

https://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/ProgrammableLinguisticInterface.html

After a quick read through the docs what I couldn't find was if you could actually extend the 'main' natural language grammar or program the interface to have such extensions. Maybe this is possible by manipulating a global set of grammar rules or using some functions I'm missing.

Building on the natural language interface used with Mathematica would be a great project. Any advice if this is possible?

Here is a concrete example. I'm thinking of something along the lines of being able to say:

```
"set the value of l to be MSE[4,5,{k,j}]"
```

so I can then use the commands:

```
"set mylist to {l}"
"the head of the first element of mylist"
```

The current idea is to be able to add to the grammar rules of Mathematica's main natural language parser so that the natural language interface would be able to handle new facts, phrases and functionality. Can this be done, or do you have to make a custom parser from scratch to handle the whole new language using the (ample) framework of language datatypes provided by the build in interpreters?

Comment: Welcome to Mathematica.SE! I suggest the following: 1) As you receive help, try to give it too, by answering questions in your area of expertise. 2) Take the [tour](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/tour)! 3) When you see good questions and answers, vote them up by [clicking the gray triangles](http://i.stack.imgur.com/eNrdG.png), because the credibility of the system is based on the reputation gained by users sharing their knowledge. Also, please remember to accept the answer, if any, that solves your problem, by [clicking the checkmark sign](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/)!

Comment: This seems a very broad question.  This site tends to be for more specific questions.

Comment: I'm really just asking about the possibility of programming the interface, not about how to.

Comment: Could you give an example of what you want to do? It's not clear to me.

Comment: The natural language parser is in the cloud. AFAIK users have no access to it.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because the OP is asking for a capability that does not exist in any version of _Mathematica_ released so far.

Comment: Given the discussion it seems that, because the natural language parser is in the cloud, there is no way to program or modify it.

Comment: The head in the usual sense is not the 1st part, but the 0th. This would make the "head of the head of the list" `Symbol`, not `1`. While I think that what you ask for is impossible, these confusing instructions could make it doubly so!

Comment: "because the natural language parser is in the cloud, there is no way to program" part is incorrect. Well, I can't but it doesn't mean there is no way.

Comment: @Kuba You missed the "given the discussion it seems that" part - if no one here can do it, then it is fair to say that it seems like it cannot be done. The comment about the parser being in the cloud is a reference to m_goldberg's comment.

Comment: @C.E. I certainly missed something :) but I still claim that OP's statement is to strong to defend itself :)

Comment: @C.E. Maybe I missinterpreted "program" as being able to create something like Anton has shown, in opposite to "modify" existing cloud parser.

Comment: @Kuba Yeah, when I answered the question I thought that it was more about the possibility to do it and not so much about modifying an existing parser. (The latter still being an important part.)

Answer (score 25):

OP seems to be mostly interested in *Mathematica*'s built-in capabilities for grammar definition, parsing, and interpretation, but I think some of the questions asked can be seen and answered within a more general development perspective.

### General

> Building on the natural language interface used with Mathematica would
>   be a great project. Any advice if this is possible?

This can be done using functional parsers. See these blog posts with detailed examples:

1. ["Natural language processing with functional parsers"](https://mathematicaforprediction.wordpress.com/2014/02/13/natural-language-processing-with-functional-parsers/),
2. ["Simple time series conversational engine"](https://mathematicaforprediction.wordpress.com/2014/11/29/simple-time-series-conversational-engine/).

Here is a general answer / discussion on creating [Domain Specific Languages (DSLs)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Domain-specific_language):

- [MSE answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/109888/general-strategies-to-write-big-code-in-mathematica/110129#110129), or
- the blog post ["Creating and programming domain specific languages"](https://mathematicaforprediction.wordpress.com/2016/03/22/creating-and-programming-dsls/).

### Extending and maintaining grammars

> The idea is to be able to add to the grammar rules of the main natural
>   language parser so that the natural language interface can be extended
>   with new facts, phrases and functionality. Can this be done, or do you 
>   have to make a custom parser from scratch to handle the whole new
>   language using the (ample) framework of language datatypes provided by
>   the build in interpreters?

The package ["FunctionalParsers.m"](https://github.com/antononcube/MathematicaForPrediction/blob/master/FunctionalParsers.m) can produce parsers from [Extended Backus-Naur Form (EBNF)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Backus%E2%80%93Naur_Form) of the grammars. With that package designing grammars and adding new rules to grammars becomes a much easier task.

(Three years ago I worked with the Nuance Speech Recognition System and I was feeding that system with grammars derived from text corpuses and data bases using *Mathematica*.)

### On the concrete example

Similar to the concrete example in the question:

```
"set mylist to {l}"
"the head of the first element of mylist"
```

the [time series conversational engine](https://mathematicaforprediction.wordpress.com/2014/11/29/simple-time-series-conversational-engine/) can work with the following sequence of commands:

```
"load data file '~/example.csv'"
"least squares fit with x+Sin[x]"
"find bottom outliers"
```

(See [this movie](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wlZ5ANglVI4) also linked in the mentioned blog post.)

### Code

Using the concrete example in the question I programmed the following parsing and interpretation. I did not try to be as complete as possible, just to provide a good enough example.

Load the package:

```
Import["https://raw.githubusercontent.com/antononcube/MathematicaForPrediction/master/FunctionalParsers.m"]
```

#### EBNF

Here is a grammar that reflects the concrete example:

```
ebnfCode = "
  <command> = <assignment> | <position-query> ;
  <assignment> = ( 'set' &> <var-name> , ( 'to' | 'as' ) &> <value> ) | ( 'assign' &> <value> , 'to' &> <var-name> ) <@ Assign ;
  <var-name> = '_WordString' <@ Var ;
  <value> = '_String' <@ Value ; 
  <position-query> = ( 'element' &> <pos-int> | [ 'the' ] &> <pos-word> <& 'element' | <pos-head> ) , 'of' &> ( <position-query> | <var-name> ) <@ PositionQuery ;
  <pos-int> = 'Range[1,100]' <@ PosInt ; 
  <pos-word> = 'first' | 'second' | 'third' | 'tenth' <@ PosWord ;
  <pos-head> = [ 'the' ] &> 'head'  <@ PosInt@0& ;
  ";
```

Note the recursive definition of the `<position-query>` rule.

#### Parser generation

Generate the parsers from EBNF code.

```
GenerateParsersFromEBNF[ParseToEBNFTokens[ebnfCode]];
```

As mentioned above with this function we can easily extend existing grammars.

#### Verification

```
statements = { "assign {3,4,{4,a},5,k} to mylist", 
   "element 4 of mylist", "third element of mylist", 
   "head of mylist" , "second element of element 3 of mylist"};
ParsingTestTable[pCOMMAND, statements, "Layout" -> "Vertical"]
```

[image]

#### Interpretation

At this point we write interpreters of the parsing output.

```
Block[{Assign, PositionQuery, PosWord, wordToIntRules},
 wordToIntRules = 
  Thread[{"first", "second", "third", "tenth"} -> {1, 2, 3, 10}];
 Assign[parsed_] :=
  Block[{varName, value},
   varName = First[Cases[parsed, Var[v_] :> v, Infinity]];
   ClearAll[Evaluate@varName];
   value = 
    ToExpression@First@Cases[parsed, Value[v_] :> v, Infinity];
   With[{sn = ToExpression@varName, v = value}, 
    OwnValues[sn] = {HoldPattern[sn] :> v}]
   ];
 PositionQuery[parsedArg_] :=
  Block[{parsed = parsedArg},
   parsed = parsed /. PosWord[pw_] :> PosInt[pw /. wordToIntRules];
   If[Length[Cases[parsed, Var[v_] :> v, Infinity]] > 0,
    Part[
     ToExpression@First@Cases[parsed, Var[v_] :> v, Infinity],
     ToExpression@First@Cases[parsed, PosInt[p_] :> p, Infinity]],
    Part[
     First@DeleteCases[parsed, _PosInt],
     ToExpression@First@Cases[parsed, PosInt[p_] :> p, Infinity]
     ]
    ]
   ];
 statements = { "assign {3,4,{4,a},5,k} to mylist", 
   "element 4 of mylist", "third element of mylist", 
   "head of mylist" , "second element of element 3 of mylist"};
 ParsingTestTable[pCOMMAND, statements, "Layout" -> "Vertical"]
]
```

[image]

Comment: Great answer. Thank you.