# Shell Emulation inside Mathematica

Tags: evaluation, cells, parsing, regular-expressions

I am trying to create a Mathematica/shell syntax hybrid.
I would like the following command

```
wget -qO- "http://google.com/space line
break\"" $var
```

to be interpreted as the following.

```
wget["-qO-","http://google.com/line
break\"",var]
```

Notice there are both line breaks and escaped quotes in the command.

I will add a bounty soon.  I'm not the best at Regular Expressions but will try it myself.

Comment: How is the "command" entered and stored as a *Mathematica* object? Is it in a `FormBox` or plain `String` or...?

Comment: "Downvoters/closers please leave comments." How about, what have you tried? You can't protect yourself against this criticism by saying that you haven't tried anything. The last paragraph gives me the feeling that you know that it's not a good question, and you are making excuses for it instead of fixing it. (No downvote from me though.)

Comment: @Jens plain string.

Comment: @William Would something similar to [my answer](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/114846/34008) of ["Programmability of the Natural Language Interface"](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/114527/programmability-of-the-natural-language-interface) work for you?

Comment: @AntonAntonov The proper way to do this would be to use something like ANTLR which I believe is similar to what you have posted.  I am kinda hopeful there is an easier way.  I believe I could make the above work if it wasn't for the escaped quotes that make the regular expression rather difficult.  I think look behinds might work although I am not good at regular expressions.  Would you like me to vote reopen that question?

Comment: @William Does the parsing and interpretation happen in Mathematica or in some other environment? (It seems it is latter.)

Comment: @AntonAntonov I'm sorry I don't understand you question.  Do you mean does ANTLR work in other environment.  If you asking what I would prefer then yes I would prefer it to work in Mathematica opposed to another environment.

Comment: @William Your answer shows that you understood my question correctly. Thanks!

Comment: @C.E. I have working example now posted although I have not received any up votes yet.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

First of all, I agree, as OP mentioned in [his comment](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/114666/shell-emulation-regular-expression#comment311693_114666), [ANTLR](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANTLR) is one of the proper ways to go.

Now for this specific task, it might be easier to just compose a parser in the "dirty" way, except we don't have to go so far to regex. In my opinion Mathematica's [`StringExpression`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/StringExpression.html) is much more powerful and very suitable for the job.

All we have to do is (as OP already did in [his answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/114924/17)) to write a parser for [`CellEvaluationFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/CellEvaluationFunction.html).

However one thing should be take care of when creating the `Cell`:

The shell emulator is going to process customized commands, which are unlikely to be similar to Mathematica's syntax, so the created `Cell` should not involve any of the `Box` typesetting system. One way to ensure this is to create the `Cell` as `Cell[ "", ... ]` instead of `Cell[ BoxData[""], ... ]` (just like what happens when you convert a Cell to the "Raw InputForm"). That case the `CellEvaluationFunction` receives input as a raw string rather than Boxes, so we can avoid lots of unnecessary work.

One simple parser could be like the following:

```
Clear[shellEmu`interpretRules, shellEmu`stringMismatchMsg, shellEmu`parser]

shellEmu`interpretRules = {
            str_String /; 
                    StringMatchQ[str, "$" ~~ LetterCharacter ~~ WordCharacter ...] :> ToExpression[StringDrop[str, 1]],
            str_String /;
                    StringMatchQ[str, NumberString]                                :> ToExpression[str]
                          };

shellEmu`stringMismatchMsg[strMarkerPos_] :=
    Failure["OddQuotations", <|
            "MessageTemplate"   -> StringTemplate["Number of quotation markers should be even and positive rather than `Number`"],
            "MessageParameters" -> <|"Number" -> Length[strMarkerPos]|>
                             |>]

shellEmu`parser[inStr_String, form_] :=
    Module[{
               workStr = StringJoin["< ", inStr, " >"],
               strLen,
               strMarkerPos,
               strMarkerPosPart, nonstrMarkerPosPart,
               posMergFunc = Function[pos, Interval @@ pos // List @@ # &],
               res
           },
           strLen           = StringLength@workStr;
           strMarkerPos     = StringPosition[workStr, #][[;; , -1]] & /@ {"\"", "\\\""} // Complement @@ # &;
           strMarkerPosPart = Partition[strMarkerPos, 2, 2, {1, 1}, {}];
           If[Length[strMarkerPos] != 0 && Length[strMarkerPosPart[[-1]]] != 2,
                   Return@shellEmu`stringMismatchMsg[strMarkerPos]
             ];
           strMarkerPosPart    = strMarkerPosPart // posMergFunc;
           nonstrMarkerPosPart = {0, Sequence @@ strMarkerPosPart, strLen + 1} // Flatten // (Partition[#, 2] + {1, -1}) & // Transpose // posMergFunc;
           res = StringTake[workStr, #] & /@ {nonstrMarkerPosPart, strMarkerPosPart};
           res //
               RightComposition[
                   MapAt[ToExpression /@ # &, #, 2] &,
                   MapAt[StringSplit[#, Whitespace] & /@ # &, #, 1] &,
                   Riffle @@ # &,
                   Flatten, #[[2 ;; -2]] &,
                   MapAt[ToExpression, #, 1] &,
                   # /. shellEmu`interpretRules &,
                   #[[1]] @@ Rest[#] &
                   ]
          ]
```

With that we can now create our `ShellEmu` Cell as following:

```
Cell["", "ShellEmu",
        Evaluatable -> True,
        CellEvaluationFunction -> shellEmu`parser,

        Background -> Hue[0.09, 0.41, 0.33],

        CellMargins -> {{50, 0}, {0, 0}},
        CellFrame -> {{False, False}, {5, 5}},
        CellFrameMargins -> {{10, 10}, {10, 10}},
        CellFrameColor -> Hue[0.09, 0.41, 0.56],

        FontFamily -> "Consolas",
        FontColor -> GrayLevel[0.95],
        FontWeight -> Bold,
        Hyphenation -> False,
        FrontEnd`AutoQuoteCharacters -> {},
        FrontEnd`PasteAutoQuoteCharacters -> {}
        ] // CellPrint
```

[image: ShellEmu 1]

Note for a clearer evidence that the command has been correctly parsed, I manually copied the output as an `"Input"`-style Cell with syntax highlight.

And mismatch of quotation markers will cause a failure:

[image: ShellEmu failure]

Now obviously `CellPrint` is too cumbersome, so we're going to get the job done more automatically.

By defining a new style in the stylesheet as following

```
Cell[StyleData["ShellEmu"],
      CellFrame                -> {{False, False}, {5, 5}},
      CellMargins              -> {{50, 0}, {0, 0}},
      Evaluatable              -> True,
      CellEvaluationFunction   -> shellEmu`parser,
      GeneratedCell            -> True,
      CellAutoOverwrite        -> True,
      CellFrameMargins         -> {{10, 10}, {10, 10}},
      CellFrameColor           -> Hue[0.09, 0.41, 0.56],
      Hyphenation              -> False,
      AutoQuoteCharacters      -> {},
      PasteAutoQuoteCharacters -> {},
      MenuCommandKey           -> "L",
      FontFamily               -> "Consolas",
      FontWeight               -> Bold,
      FontColor                -> GrayLevel[0.95],
      Background               -> Hue[0.09, 0.41, 0.33]]
```

we should be able to create `"ShellEmu"` Cell simply by a shortcut <kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>L</kbd>.

We can define functions matching the parsed result, say:

```
Clear[plot]
plot[f_, var_, "from", start_, "to", end_] :=
    Module[{interm},
        Echo[Inactive[plot][f, var, "from", start, "to", end] // FullForm];
        interm = 
            Inactive[Plot][ToExpression@f, ToExpression /@ {var, start, end}];
        Echo[interm // FullForm];
        Activate[interm]
        ]
```

[image: ShellEmu 2]

Comment: Impressive work!

Comment: @AntonAntonov Thanks! I love your answer under [Programming of a natural language interface](http://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/114527/17)!

Comment: Is there any way to get piping to work in your example like something like this.  `command test | command2` or maybe `command test // command2` to be more inline with Mathematica
.

Comment: So I will be giving you the bounty if there are no other answers.  I have determined a way to get piping to work in my answer `//`.

Comment: @Liam Sorry I didn't around recently. I think you'll have to add your own parsing rule for that in `interpretRules`. Maybe using `StringSplit[ str, "|"|"//" ]`. And thank you for your bounty!

Comment: Is there a simple way to add tab completion.  Probably not but figured it wouldn't hurt to ask.

Comment: @Liam I believe it will be very hard if not impossible, especially considering that EventKey seems not able to capture Tab. One way might be retrieving keystroke information from OS API.

Answer (score 9):

I extended the original question to support piping like the following.

```
wget -qO- "http://google.com" // cat
```

and it outputs the following.

```
cat[][wget[-qO-,http://google.com][]]
```

To get the following.

```
CellPrint@
  Cell[BoxData[""], "Input", Evaluatable -> True, 
   CellEvaluationFunction -> 
    Function[
     Module[{t}, 
      t = List@
        ReplaceRepeated[NotebookRead[EvaluationCell[]][[1, 1]], 
         RowBox[{x__}] :> x];
      t = 
       Map[Module[{t = #, a, addbacksemicolon = ""}, 
          If[t[[-1]] == ";", addbacksemicolon = ";";
           t = Delete[t, -1]];

          If[Length@t >= 2 && 
            StringMatchQ[t[[1]], 
             RegularExpression["([a-zA-Z0-9])*"]] && t[[2]] == " ", 
           t = SplitBy[t, " " == # &] // DeleteCases@{" "};
           t = SplitBy[t, {"//"} == # &] // DeleteCases@{{"//"}};

           t = Map[
             Map[If[(Characters[#])[[1, 1]] == "\"", #, 
                 StringJoin[{"\"", #, "\""}]] &, #] &, t];

           t = Map[
             StringJoin[StringTrim[#[[1]], "\""], "[", 
               StringJoin@Riffle[#[[2 ;;]], ","], "]"] &, t];
           (*Print["beforeRiffleStringJoin",t];*)

           t[[1]] = t[[1]] <> "[]";

           t = StringJoin@Riffle[t, " // "] <> "" <> 
             addbacksemicolon;
           (* Print@t;*)
           t, t]] &,
        t = (SplitBy[If[Depth[t] == 2, t, t[[1]]], 
            "\[IndentingNewLine]" == # &] // 
           DeleteCases@{"\[IndentingNewLine]"});
        t
        ];
      t = ToExpression@StringJoin@Riffle[t, "\[IndentingNewLine]"];
      t
      ]]];
cd[x_] := Function[SetDirectory[x];]
fn = Function[Null, 
   ReplacePart[
    Function @@ 
     Hold[Null, Quiet[## &, {Function::slotn}], HoldAll], {2, 1, 0} ->
      Function @@ Hold[##]], HoldAll];
cmds = {echo, cat, ls, wget, grep, ps, top, df, killv, rm, cp, mv, 
   cat, mount, chmod, chown, passwd, mkdir, ifconfig, uname, whereis, 
   whatis, locate, find, sed, awk, diff , sort, xargs, uname, 
   ifconfig, locate , man, tail, less, ping, date};
Map[Function[{f},
   With[{n = ToString[Unevaluated[f]]},
    f[x___ : String] := fn[
       Import[
        "!LD_LIBRARY_PATH= " <> 
         If[ToString@#1 == "#1", "", "echo \"" <> #1 <> "\" | "] <> 
         n <> " " <> StringJoin@Riffle[{x}, " "], "Text"]
       ];
    ]
   ], cmds];
```

Comment: Cool! I've played with it a little bit and it's probably better to replace the last `Print` with `CellPrint[
 ExpressionCell[
  Symbol[StringTrim[t[[1]], "\""]] @@ ToString /@ t[[2 ;;]], 
  "Output"]]`

Comment: @swish thank you for the upvote(if it was you)!  Your code does appear to be shorter I will mess with it a bit.  I am trying to figure out if I can generalize the approach above to work for more then just one line.