# Is there a function to convert an English description to an expression?

Tags: output-formatting, string-manipulation, formatting, conversion

I know I can write:

```
SpokenString[a + b^2]
```

And then obtain as output:

```
"a plus b squared"
```

What about the opposite, something like:

```
ReadString["a plus b squared"]
```

And then obtain as output (without access to the internet, e.g., calling Wolfram Alpha):

```
a + b^2
```

Comment: [SpokenString](http://reference.wolfram.com/mathematica/ref/SpokenString.html)?

Comment: Yes, found it right after. Changed my question to ask if there is a way to do the reverse without calling WolframAlpha

Comment: `SpokenString` is a great suggestion to go from code -> prose. If you want to go from prose -> code, I recommend checking out inputs in wolframalpha, like http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integrate+error+function+of+x+divided+by+x+from+zero+to+nine.

Comment: @Luxspes I unfortunately seemed to have missed your edit by a few minutes. If you don't want to call W|A I am not sure your problem is solvable without MUCH work

Comment: if you want to restrict input to a handful of "operators" maybe you could do it. Otherwise to be really general you would pretty much be reinventing alpha.

Comment: Related: [https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/114527/34008](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/114527/34008).

Answer (score 3):

Assuming:

> without calling Wolfram Alpha

means you just want an in-product approach as opposed to a web based approach, you could use <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>=</kbd> or the [`WolframAlpha`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/WolframAlpha) function. For example:

```
WolframAlpha["a plus b squared", "MathematicaParse"]
```

> HoldComplete[a + b^2]

If you really mean that you don't want to use anything based on Wolfram|Alpha, then I think you will need to create your own parser.

Comment: I just want to know if a local function to do it exists

Comment: @Luxspes Meaning you want a function that you can use without access to the internet? If so, I think you're out of luck.

Comment: Is there a way to be sure?